# Troubleshooting RPC client when it SEGV's on 0x8 addr

Tags: debugging, rpc, segmentation-fault

Need some options for troubleshooting this situation.  Below is some of what I've done and I cannot determine how I get a SIGSEGV on a 0x8 address.  No references have that address.  Since this is generated by rpcgen and appears to be correct I'm at a loss one where to look next.  (RHEL 7.2, x86, gcc 4.8.5)

Thanks for any options.

```
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6.1-80.el7
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later
<http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law. √äype "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /home/tdavis/deepspace/RL/rl/rl/dsvwrite...done.
[New LWP 19338]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `dsvwrite if=/root/anaconda-ks.cfg
fid=anaconda-ks.cfg'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0 0x000000000048fb0d in lt_open_1 (argp=0x7ffdafed6f40, clnt=0x0) at ds_clnt.c:93
93          memset((char *)&clnt_res, 0, sizeof(clnt_res));
(gdb) bt
#0 0x000000000048fb0d in lt_open_1 (argp=0x7ffdafed6f40, clnt=0x0) at ds_clnt.c:93
#1 0x00000000004552e2 in ltr_open (lt=0xd003a0, lbl=0x7ffdafed71d0, mode=2, p_start=0) at ds_lib.c:373
#2 0x0000000000441501 in lt_open (lt=0xd003a0, lbl=0x7ffdafed71d0, mode=2, p_start=0) at lt.c:383
#3 0x000000000042fa9d in vs_xopen (vsd=0, oflg=2, fs=0x7ffdafed7460) at rx.c:870
#4 0x000000000042ce55 in vs_open (vsd=0, oflg=2, fs=0x7ffdafed76f0) at rx.c:349
#5 0x000000000040b30c in rlvwrite (argc=3, argv=0x7ffdafed7a38) at xcom.c:685
#6 0x00000000004983c5 in main_mux (argc=3, argv=0x7ffdafed7a38) at main_man.c:87
#7 0x0000000000404881 in main (argc=3, argv=0x7ffdafed7a38) at rcom.c:376
(gdb) l
88  open_res *
89  lt_open_1(open_prm *argp, CLIENT *clnt)
90  {
91          static open_res clnt_res;
92
93          memset((char *)&clnt_res, 0, sizeof(clnt_res));
94          if (clnt_call (clnt, LT_OPEN,
95                  (xdrproc_t) xdr_open_prm, (caddr_t) argp,
96                  (xdrproc_t) xdr_open_res, (caddr_t) &clnt_res,
97                  TIMEOUT) != RPC_SUCCESS) {
(gdb)98                    return (NULL);
99          }
100         return (&clnt_res);
101 }
102
103 close_res *
104 lt_close_1(close_prm *argp, CLIENT *clnt)
105 {   106         static close_res clnt_res;
107
(gdb) p clnt_res
$1 = {lbl = {tran = 0, pad = 0, len = 0, format = 0, vol = 0x0, uvol = 0x0, file = 0x0,√äfile = 0x0, unl = 0x0}, status = 0, terrn = 0, uerrno = 0, rl_system = 0,√äl_assert = 0}
(gdb) p $_siginfo
$2 = {si_signo = 11, si_errno = 0, si_code = 1, _sifields = {_pad = {8,√ä <repeats 27 times>}, _kill = {si_pid = 8, si_uid = 0}, _imer = {si_tid = 8,√äi_overrun = 0, si_sigval = {sival_int = 0, sival_ptr = 0x0}}, _rt = {si_pid = 8,√äi_uid = 0, si_sigval = {sival_i = 0, sival_ptr = 0x0}}, _sigchld = { si_pid = 8, si_uid = 0, si_status = 0, si_utime = 0, si_stime = 0}, **sigfault = { si_addr = 0x8}**, _sigpoll = {si_band = 8, si_fd = 0}}}
(gdb) quit
```

Comment: valgrind confirms the addr but when stepping into clnt_call or memset it will SEGV.  Trapping SEGV offers no help.  Always 0x8 in $_siginfo's si_addr.

Comment: ==32495== Invalid read of size 8  
        ==32495==    at 0x48FB21: lt_open_1 (ds_clnt.c:94)  
        ==32495==    by 0x4552E1: ltr_open (ds_lib.c:387)  
        ==32495==    by 0x441500: lt_open (lt.c:383)  
        ==32495==    by 0x42FA9C: vs_xopen (rx.c:870)  
        ==32495==    by 0x42CE54: vs_open (rx.c:349)  
        ==32495==    by 0x40B30B: rlvwrite (xcom.c:685)  
        ==32495==    by 0x4983D8: main_mux (main_man.c:87)  
        ==32495==    by 0x404880: main (rcom.c:376)  
        ==32495==  Address 0x8 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd

Comment: Problem solved.  Still not sure how to debug this type of issue other than solving the stupid user scenario.  The problem was manifested due to an errant ';'.  Would have been nice if there was some clue from gdb.  Ultimately I had to read the code path for the 1000th time before seeing the change in logic.  figured I should update so people don't waste any more bandwidth.